# How do I restore huge script.sql database to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can not import database to my PC. Both SQL databases are 'sql server 2008', but different version. Then, how can I import database to my pc's SQL Server 2008?

I have tried,

1st try:-

CALL sqlcmd -w 125 -S %(local)% -d %REBOX% -U%sa% -P%sql% -l30 -b -I -i  "E:\db.sql"

But the below error occurred,
[image]

2nd try:-
[image]

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

First error is a connection error, it is saying it cannot connect to the SQL Server specified.  Looking at your server - `%(local)%`.  Echo that value, and if it is not a valid value, then that is the issue. If it is a valid value, then ensure you can ping it/access it.

Second error - you cannot restore a database backup from a higher version of SQL Server.  Looks like you are trying to restore a backup from SQL 2008 R2 to server with SQL 2008 RTM.  Your best bet is to upgrade your version of SQL to SQL 2008 R2 or higher, then do the restore.

Comment: I have done 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME', now got server name after applied cmd command like this: CALL sqlcmd -w 125 -S %DESKTOP-QT255TT% -d %REBOX% -U%sa% -P%sql% -l30 -b -I -i  "E:\db.sql"

Comment: Vet did of the percent signs around the server name, it's supposed to denote a variable, which you do not need since you are hard coding the server name.

Comment: What you want is this, assuming you are not using variables at all: `sqlcmd -w 125 -S "DESKTOP-QT255TT" -d REBOX -U sa -P sql -l30 -b -I -i "E:\db.sql" `

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty database in 2008.
I think you can generate scripts for 2008 and execute them against the database that you created.

There is another forum on Stack Overflow which explains it in detail:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20588/restore-sql-server-2012-backup-to-a-sql-server-2008-database

Cheers
Nithin